# Cloud Function failing to parse JSON and write to Cloud Firestore from Webhook

Tags: node.js, json, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a Webhook that POSTs a JSON to my Cloud Function Trigger URL.

I want the Cloud Function to parse the JSON and write it to my Cloud Firestore.

I've tested the Webhook on webhook.site & requestbin.com : they are both receiving the POST request perfectly.

I am guessing that there is some syntax problem somewhere here, around the payload or req.body.

```js
exports.wooCommerceWebhook = async (req, res) => {
    const payload = req.body;
```

Additionally, this is not an authenticated request, and I deployed the function through the Google Cloud Platform - Cloud Function Console. I did not deploy this through the CLI, or through an application setup with firebase.

**index.js**

```js
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
admin.initializeApp();

exports.wooCommerceWebhook = async (req, res) => {
    const payload = req.body;

    // Write to Firestore - People Collection
    await admin.firestore().collection("people").doc().set({
        people_Email: payload.billing.email,
        people_FirstName: payload.billing.first_name,
        people_LastName: payload.billing.last_name,
    });

    return res.status(200).end();

};
```

**package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "sample-http",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
      "firebase-admin": "^9.4.2"
  }
}
```

**My Webhook that delivers a POST JSON to my Cloud Function URL:**

```json
{
     "billing": {
          "email": "test@test.com",
          "first_name": "First",
          "last_name": "Last"
     }
}
```

**EDIT:**
**I've added**

```js
.catch((err) => { console.log(err); })
```

**and now my logs are returning:**

```
Unhandled rejection
TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined at exports.wooCommerceWebhook (/workspace/index.js:18:43)
at /layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/invoker.js:98:17
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11)
Function execution took 599 ms, finished with status: 'crash'
Error detected in test-function-1
```

Comment: I've used requestbin just to verify that I am getting the correct JSON to a URL, requestbin is not writing to the Firestore. Checking my Firestore rules is a good idea, thank you.

Comment: I deleted my initial comment as you're using the admin-sdk so I don't think the firestore rules would be an issue. Are you setting a content-type json header on your request to the cloud function? It might be worth running through these docs https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http Also trying logging something out as the first line of your request handler and/or the req.body on your payload, you should at least see some output in your logs if it's hitting that portion of the code to narrow it down,

Comment: Yes I have a content-type json header on the webhook POST request. The Logs within the cloud function console are saying that the trigger URL is being hit. I think my syntax for parsing and writing to the Cloud Firestore may be incorrect.

Comment: trying adding a `.catch(err => { console.error(err)});` onto the end of your insert and seeing if you get any more info

Comment: like this? `return res.status(200).end().catch((err) => { console.log(err); });`

Comment: No like `await admin.firestore().collection("people").doc().set({
        people_Email: payload.billing.email,
        people_FirstName: payload.billing.first_name,
        people_LastName: payload.billing.last_name,
    }).catch((err) => { console.log(err); });` so you can see if the insert returns an error

Comment: I've added the new logs to the original post, and will continue my investigation.

Comment: So it looks like the "billing" object isn't defined. Perhaps you need to do JSON.parse(req.body) first

Comment: `exports.wooCommerceWebhook = async (req, res) => { const payload = JSON.parse(req.body);` Adding JSON.parse now returns a 403 error from the web hook.

Comment: Have you tried logging out your `payload` variable to see what it is? e.g `console.log("payload", payload);` and `console.log("type is  ", typeof payload);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to declare each field's data type first.

```js
let billing = "";
let people_Email = "";
let people_FirstName = "";
let people_LastName = "";
```

Comment: Should I have used var or let?